# Getting "No such file or directory" error when i give any command in terminal in mac machine OS high sierra

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, macos-high-sierra

It was working fine until now but don't know what the issue is? Even when i give the command "clear", it is showing "No such file or directory".

Can anyone please help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please find the snapshot below:

Comment: Vigneshwars-MacBook-Air:~ vigneshwar$ touch comm.txt
-bash: touch: No such file or directory
Vigneshwars-MacBook-Air:~ vigneshwar$ open ~/.bash_Profile
-bash: open: No such file or directory
Vigneshwars-MacBook-Air:~ vigneshwar$ clear
-bash: clear: No such file or directory
Vigneshwars-MacBook-Air:~ vigneshwar$

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: You probably broke your PATH somehow. Use full paths (e.g. `/usr/bin/open .bash_profile`) to run commands until you figure out which configuration file is to blame and you can fix it.

Comment: If you don't know the full path, use the shell built-in command `type` to find out: `type open` outputs `open is /usr/bin/open`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the help! It works with the above command. Could you please help me on how to fix this issue? I am new to MAC OS as I am a windows user. Thanks!